# Scrollbar tkinter duda

Tags: python, tkinter, botón, canvas, scrollbar

Quizás la consulta que os voy a hacer es una tontería de mi propio código que no veo, pero quiero que en la ventana que he creado, que he simplificado todo lo que lleva dentro, el scroll que contiene los botones de la derecha rellene todo el tamaño de ventana y que se ajuste al tamaño de los botones, os dejo el código y una pequeña imagen para que se vea bien.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox #libreria IMPRESCINDIBLE para meter ventanas emergentes
from tkinter import filedialog #libreria que necesito para estas ventanas
from tkinter import ttk #libreria que necesito para estas ventanas

raiz=Tk()

raiz.resizable(0,0) 

framebotones=Frame(raiz, width=200, height=610)
framebotones.pack(side="right",anchor="n") 
framebotones.config(relief="ridge",bd="5")

canvasbotones=Canvas(framebotones)
canvasbotones.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

my_scrolbar=ttk.Scrollbar(framebotones, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvasbotones.yview)
my_scrolbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

canvasbotones.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrolbar.set)
canvasbotones.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvasbotones.configure(scrollregion=canvasbotones.bbox("all")))

second_frame= Frame(canvasbotones)

canvasbotones.create_window(0, 0, window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

for thing in range (100):
    Button(second_frame, text=f"Boton {thing}").grid(row=thing,column=0)
    
Myframe2=Frame(raiz, width=100, height=50) #creación del frame como contenedor de widgets
Myframe2.pack() #empaquetamiento del frame 

Canvas=Canvas(raiz, width=1000, height=600) #creación del canvas como contenedor de widgets
Canvas.pack(side="right", anchor="n") #empaquetamiento del canvas 
Canvas.config(relief="ridge",bd="5")
vcto_boton=Button(Canvas, text="Siguiente",command=lambda:[salerectangulos(Canvas)])
vcto_boton.place(x=200, y=200)

raiz.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que ajustar manualmente el ancho de uno de uno de los dos componentes y dejar el otro que se expanda, tkinter no tiene equivalente de cosas como `wxSplitterWindow`, aparte de eso tampoco tiene soporte para scroll, pero solo se puede hacer porque algunos componentes puede hacer scroll y el canvas, siendo uno de ellos, deja enganchar un frame dentro (el `Scrolable_Frame` es de este [otro post mio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68052735/add-scrollbar-to-updating-label-in-tkinter-python/68056722#68056722), pero puedes encontrar variantes que hacen lo mismo en otros post por si no hace exactamente lo que necesitas)

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Ventana(tk.Tk):

    marco_r_ratio = 0.3

    def on_resize(self, _):
        self.frame_r.config(width=int(
            self.winfo_width() * self.marco_r_ratio)
        )

    def on_button_seleccion(self):
        if self.seleccionado is not None:
            print('Boton {0} seleccionado'.format(
                self.seleccionado
            ))
        else:
            print('Ninguno seleccionado')

    def on_button_lista(self, n):
        print('Boton {0} presionado'.format(n))
        self.seleccionado = n

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry('800x600+300+300')

        self.seleccionado = None

        self.frame_l = tk.Frame(self, bg='#5A5A5A')
        self.frame_l.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.button_select = tk.Button(
                self.frame_l, text='Seleccionado',
                command=self.on_button_seleccion
        )
        self.button_select.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

        self.frame_r = Scrolable_Frame(self)
        self.frame_r.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.on_resize(None)

        self.botones = []
        for i in range(100):
            boton = tk.Button(
                self.frame_r.get(), text='Botton {0}'.format(i),
                command=lambda n=i: self.on_button_lista(n)
            )
            boton.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)
            self.botones.append(boton)

        self.bind('<Configure>', self.on_resize)

class Scrolable_Frame(tk.Frame):

    def get(self):
        return self.interior

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.scroll = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(
            self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
            yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        self.scroll.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self.canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self.interior = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        interior_id = self.canvas.create_window(
            0, 0, window=self.interior, anchor=tk.NW
        )

        def _configure_interior(_):
            size = (self.interior.winfo_reqwidth(), self.interior.winfo_reqheight())
            self.canvas.config(scrollregion="0 0 %s %s" % size)
            if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                self.canvas.config(width=self.interior.winfo_reqwidth())
        self.interior.bind('<Configure>', _configure_interior)

        def _configure_canvas(_):
            if self.interior.winfo_reqwidth() != self.canvas.winfo_width():
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(interior_id, width=self.canvas.winfo_width())
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', _configure_canvas)

        def _on_mousewheel(event):
            self.canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), 'units')
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Ventana()
    app.mainloop()
```

Algo que deberías tener en cuenta es añadir el scroll a componentes lo hace todo muy lento y no es algo que puedas solucionar, tkinter necesita correr en el hilo principal, el problema no es tener demasiados componentes cargado en memoria sino el tiempo de dibujo así que usar menus desplegables es recomendable

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda! Me quedo con el consejo de la cantidad de memoria que ocupa el scroll. Me guardo la forma de resolver el problema por si es muy necesario y lo redimensiono para que el scroll no sea necesario